# Criar pastas trunk, branch e tag no subversion em um repositório já existente

Tags: versionamento, svn

Tenho um projeto que está em um repositório no **subversion**, porém o mesmo **NÃO** está dentro das pastas recomendadas: trunk, branch e tag. Como se a pasta que o projeto se encontra fosse o próprio trunk.
Eu posso criar as 3 pastas e colocar o projeto na pasta trunk, depois criar tags/branches de revisões anteriores sem problemas?

Comment: Você pode criar as 3 pastas sem problemas, sempre vai poder voltar atrás para buscar algo que queira, a questão é que a nova pasta não terá os históricos de alterações já realizadas, aí você teria que ir na raiz do projeto e buscar suas versões para buscar uma revision anterior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, pode. Faça um backup do seu repositório antes desta operação.

Crie as pastas `trunk` e `branch`, mova o projeto da pasta raiz para a pasta `trunk` usando a operação `rename`. Deste modo você manterá o histórico de alterações dos arquivos.

Quando precisar de um branch, use a operação `branch/tag` para criá-lo em uma subpasta da pasta `branch`. Assim quando você olhar o histórico de alterações de um arquivo neste branch, você verá também as alterações feitas anteriormente ao próprio branch (não por causa da hierarquia de pastas mas simplesmente porque você usou a operação `branch/tag`).

Recomendo usar o "explorer" ou "navigator" do Tortoise para criar as pastas e fazer rename. É mais fácil e fica menos sujeito a erros do que fazer localmente para depois commitar.

Combine com seu time para que ninguém tenha nenhum commit pendente antes da operação - isso também diminui as chances de enfrentar problemas.

Não vejo necessidade da pasta `tag`. Pelo menos as versões do Subversion que utilizei não possuem recurso especial de `tag`; tag e branch, ao menos nestas versões do Subversion, são a mesma coisa.

Comment: Muito bom não tinha pensado na operação `rename` pode ajudar muito, mas você poderá realizar apenas se tiver uma unica pasta na raiz do versionamento.

Comment: @DiegoSantos A operação `rename` funciona tanto em pasta quanto em arquivos, de modo que você pode selecionar tudo que estiver na raiz (exceto a pasta `trunk` que você acabou de criar, naturalmente) e executar a operação `rename` de modo a mover tudo de uma vez para a pasta trunk.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar as 3 pastas na mão sem problemas(`trunk`, `branch` e `tag`), alguns softwares como `Tortoise` tem a opção de criar essa estrutura.

O mais importante é que sempre vai poder voltar atrás para buscar algo que queira,
um empecilho é que as novas pastas não terão os históricos de alterações já realizadas,
aí você teria que ir na raiz do projeto e buscar suas versões para encontrar o histórico de alterações. Espero ter ajudado.